# Finding the Startup Assembly at Design Time in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF MarkupExtension that needs to access resources in the default resource assembly. Extension works fine at runtime, but fails in the designer as the extension can't find the default resources in the startup assembly. In order to load up a ResourceManager I need to know what assembly to load the resources from.

At runtime I can handle this easily by passing in an Assembly at Initialization - that works just fine.

However, at Design Time none of this startup code executes so the designer bombs and fails to load the page. So how can I get one of the following generically (without referencing specific application types):

- The Application's startup assembly
  (ie. the WPF EXE)
- The Current XAML Document the Markup Extension is hosted on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no easy and clean way to do that... I use the following method, which looks for an assembly that has an entry-point (i.e. an executable assembly) and contains a class derived from System.Windows.Application :

```
    public static Assembly GetEntryAssembly()
    {
        // Should work at runtime
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

        // Design time
        if (asm == null)
        {
            asm = (
                   from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                   where a.EntryPoint != null
                   && a.GetTypes().Any(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(System.Windows.Application)))
                   select a
                  ).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return asm;
    }
```

This code needs to be adjusted for specific needs (for instance, it won't work for a WPF control library)

If you prefer to retrieve the XAML root element, you could find some inspiration in the [code of a markup extension](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/03/17/wpf-using-inputbindings-with-the-mvvm-pattern/) I wrote some time ago. It finds the root element by using reflection on private/internal fields.

Comment: Ah yes, I had found the Context properties before and dismissed using private reflection. But now that I think about this scenario is primarily for the designer so trust issues should not be a problem.

Thanks I think this points me in the right direction.

Comment: The above code works in the designer with and finding the startup assembly. That still leaves controls in other assemblies but that's fairly minor - markup extension default can handle that.

FWIW, private reflection code in your post is useful, but unfortunately it fails in the designer. Apparently the designer runs in partial trust after all and the attempt at private Reflection fails. Not only that it aborts code 
completely - an exception block doesn't capture it.

Comment: Strange... for me it doesn't crash the designer. Anyway, it's just a dirty workaround to bind InputBinding commands to ViewModel commands.

Comment: Thomas, it looks like in the VS Designer it works. In Blend is where it bombs for me without error - just aborts without even catching in my exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

Assembly.GetEntryAssembly.FullName will give you #1. For your other problem, wouldn't Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly do it?

Comment: That works at runtime, but not at design time since the designer takes over the application. I need to get a ref to the start assembly at design time.

The problem is the markup extension is in a separate assembly. 

Right now I've moved it to the main assembly and reference the assembly that way - that works, but i really need to have the extension in a separate assembly.